# Cannot install windows to brand new HDD

Tags: hard-drive, windows-installation

I started a new installation of windows 7 starter and an error (attached image) showed up. [image]

Edit: the issue still remains, the edit before was just bad config of cmos

Also I receive some kind of I/O error in CMD (Shift + F10).

Comment: I assume you clicked 'New' to create a new partition, and then got the error?

Comment: @spikey_richie no, i clicked next

Comment: You need to click 'New' first to create a new partition in the unallocated space. Then you can click next.

Comment: @spikey_richie no you don't, I never do and it installs just fine, but it might fix the issue.

Comment: @moab Maybe it's just force of habit then, but I've always created a new partition before clicking Next.

Comment: Yeah I did too then figured out I could skip that step when there was an unallocated partition on a hard drive., never had an issue so far.

Comment: Windows 7 will not be supported after January 14, 2020. In 12 days from now Windows 7 will turn into a Windows XP pumpkin..

Comment: @karel that doesn't mean people can't still install it...

Comment: Pumpkins are for eating, not surfing the internet.

Comment: Could it be because I have bad ISO?

Comment: @TBQP you have a bad ISO? Then get a good one. Also, what do you mean by "Also I receive some kind of I/O error in CMD" ?

Comment: Sometimes I've found it necessary to clean or wipe a new drive before the Windows installer could use it. Press F8 to open a command prompt, and use diskpart to clean the new drive, then try running the installer again.

Comment: @spikey_richie Windows setup will auto-configure disk partitions on a disk with no partitions by clicking _Next_.

Comment: @TBQP CMOS has nothing to do with the disk... CMOS is there only to enable the motherboard's firmware (BIOS or UEFI) to retain its memory.  Is the drive physically attached to the PC via SATA or is it connected via USB (IIRC, Windows 7 doesn't allow installation to a drive connected via USB).

Comment: Where did you got a "brand new" HDD of 240GB size? Such drives are almost antique and can't be brand new. Therefore I would assume that you have bought a defect drive.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your CMOS battery and reload standard settings before continuing.